# CvInvoke.cvReleaseImage() usage in EmguCV (3.1)

Tags: c#, image-processing, garbage-collection, emgucv, using-statement

I program my app in C# using visual studio 2013. I use EmguCV(3.1) for this purpose. I Load each image file from folder and do some process on it. My app is some thing like this:

```
private void SomeProcessesOnSingleImage(String filePath)
{
    // Some Bitmap instances
    // Some Image<Gray, Byte> instances
    // Some Image<Bgr, Byte> instances
    // Some UMat instances

    // Do some processes
    // Save file
}
private void BatchProcessor()
{
    String[] filePathes = Directory.GetFiles(d.SelectedPath);
    foreach(String path in filePathes)
    {
        SomeProcessesOnSingleImage(path);
    }
}
```

After about 1 minute from running my app, it does not respond and I see this message about my graphic card:

[image]

Now, My questions are:

1. Should I release `Image< , >` or `UMat` using `CvInvoke.cvReleaseImage()` or `Garbage collector` do it?
2. Should I use `using` for `Bitmap` and other similar instances?
3. In case of **NO** for questions above, how can I fix it?

I note that my app do it works perfectly when I use single Image (when I just call `SomeProcessesOnSingleImage` method).

*UPDATE 1: I use OpenCL (UseOpenCL = true)*

Answer (score -1):

You should release used memory by your image object by "using statement". or you can use CvInvoke.cvReleaseImage().